# sliding menu's panel on mouseover throught out the page

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to CSS and jquery and I am seeking help regarding sliding menus's panel that stays throughout the page. This should work when the mouse over is done. This is what I'm talking about:
[image]

it stays like that until mouse over is done. when on mouse over, the entire section to slide like this:

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post code or a demo. You can't expect folks to write your project from scratch for you.

Comment: hotdow1987, welcome to Stack-overflow. I suggest you to read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq before going any further. Actually, this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear and not useful and  is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed. You can try to present your coding context on jsFiddle for a start.

Answer (score 0):

ther is very simple sliding menu build only in css

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;

}
.menu ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px;
    top:0;
    width: 200px;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;   
    transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover ul {
    left: 0;

}
.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin:0 10px;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
.menu li a {
    color: #999;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/sqJyw/

Comment: thank you so much. Thats a good start. so, if I have to create a text lets say contacts and move that along with the entire item list then how do i proceed? (same as the gif)